# Is it considered "correct" to use a template for a function/class that only accepts subclasses of a specific class?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say hypothetically that I am making a game and in that game there are spawning  points `class SpawnArea` for monsters' classes that inherit from `class Monster`. Would it be correct to use a template knowing that I am not expecting just any class and `Spawn` will only accept a specific subset of classes?   I would like to use a template cause it's the only way I'm aware of to pass a class type as argument for the purpose of constructing instances of a specific class. Is there any more elegant way to write a class who's instances are used to construct multiple instances of some other specific class?

I read this:

[Make a template accept a specific class/family of classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111501/make-a-template-accept-a-specific-class-family-of-classes)

It did not discuss the issue of constructing instances of a specific set of classes.

Comment: More elegant than what? Show what you have now. It's not at all clear from your description what `Spawn` is supposed to be doing with its parameter.

Comment: Constraining the possible template arguments of a template is what Concepts and Constraints have been developed for. Until they're in the Standard, you can use `static_assert` and SFINAE-techniques; for example using `std::is_base_of`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite common, actually almost all templates have certain requirements towards their arguments. Those are usually implicitly clear from how the template parameter is used, but you can improve the error messages by using [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types). In C++11, they are available from the standard library via `#include <type_traits>`, otherwise look into [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html).

With C++11, the usage is quite simple when you also use `static_assert`:

```
template< typename T >
std::shared_ptr< T > spawn()
{
    // make this the first line in your function to get errors early.
    // also note that you can use any compile-time check you like.
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< Monster, T >::value,
                   "T is not derived from Monster" );

    // the rest of your code follows here.
    // ...
    // return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you have to use a template function (which I guess could be done better using factory functions) and your compiler supports c++11 (most current compilers do), you could restrict your template function using type_traits like:

```
#include <type_traits>
...
template <typename MonsterT,
          class = typename std::enable_if<
              std::is_base_of<Monster, MonsterT>::value
          >::type
>
std::shared_ptr<MonsterT> spawn() { ... }
```

This way the compiler won't accept

```
spawn<SomeType>()
```

if SomeType is not derived of Monster. A way more generic solution would be concepts, however unfortunately they are not part of c++11/c++14 - some people consider the Boost Concept Check library suitable enough for that purpose.

Like I said above using template functions may not be the wisest choice (one of the problems being the tendency to prevent a clear and concise documentation) - just wanted to show a way to "restrict" templates for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

I think using SFINAE to emulate the template constraints of Concepts Lite is useful.

Consider a shape class hierarchy like this:

```
/* Base class. */
class Shape { /* ... */ };

/* Derived classes. */
class Circle : public Shape { /* ... */ };
class Square : public Shape { /* ... */ };
class Triangle : public Shape { /* ... */ };
```

#### Peek into Concepts Lite

First, let's look at a simple usage pattern of constraints in Concepts Lite similar to the examples shown in section 2.1 in [N3580](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf):

```
/* SomeShape concept. */
template <typename T>
concept bool SomeShape() { return std::is_base_of<Shape, T>::value; }

/* T must meet SomeShape concept. */
template <SomeShape T>
double GetArea(const T &shape) { /* ... */ }
```

which is equivalent to

```
template <typename T>
requires SomeShape<T>()
double GetArea(const T &shape) { /* ... */ }
```

#### Emulation with `std::enable_if` as the return type.

Now, we can't get the first form which is clearly prettier, but we could emulate the second form with `std::enable_if`.

```
/* SomeShape concept. */
template <typename T>
constexpr bool SomeShape() { return std::is_base_of<Shape, T>::value; }

/* Force T to be specified. */
template <bool B, typename T>
using requires = std::enable_if_t<B, T>;
```

can be used like so:

```
// Awkward indenting to make it look similar to the second form.
template <typename T>
requires<SomeShape<T>(),
double> GetArea(const T &shape) { /* ... */ }
```

#### Multiple constraints

It's easy to compose multiple constraints since the result simply needs to be a compile-time boolean value. Suppose we didn't have `std::is_arithmetic` available to us, we could either implement it, or if it's only of one-time use, we can just use it inline like so:

```
template <typename Val>
requires<std::is_integral<Val>::value || std::is_floating_point<Val>::value,
Val> DoubleMe(const Val &val) {
  return val + val;
}
```

#### Limitations of putting `std::enable_if` as the return type

- Doesn't work for things that don't have a return type such as constructors.
- Doesn't work with return type deduction using `auto` and `-> decltype(/* ... */)`

**NOTE**: `std::enable_if` can go in the *template-parameter-list* to make it work with constructors and return type deduction, but it doesn't work with variadic templates. If this is your preferred option, check out [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699081/can-i-overload-functions-with-type-traits/20699983#20699983),

#### Difference between SFINAE with `std::enable_if` and `static_assert`

The important difference between the two is that with `std::enable_if`, the function does not get considered during overload resolution. So if you know you won't have overloads, you may prefer to simply use `static_assert` since you'll get a better error message (assuming you choose a better one of course).

Consider the following overloaded functions:

```
template <typename T>
requires<SomeShape<T>(),
void> Print(const T &shape) {
  std::cout << shape << std::endl;
}

void Print(double val) {
  std::cout << std::showpoint << val << std::endl;
}
```

Calling `Print(2.0);` will of course bind to the `void Print(double val);` overload. `Print(1);` also bind to `void Print(double val);` because `void Print(const T &shape);` does not get considered for overload resolution and `int` is implicitly convertible to `double`.

Now consider what happens if we used `static_assert` instead.

```
template <typename T>
void Print(const T &shape) {
  static_assert(SomeShape<T>(), "T must be a Shape!");
  std::cout << shape << std::endl;
}

void Print(double val) {
  std::cout << std::showpoint << val << std::endl;
}
```

Calling `Print(1)` this time binds to the first version because `void Print(const T &shape);` which gets instantiated to `void Print(const int &shape)` which is a better match than `void Print(double val);`. We then hit the `static_assert` which gives us a compile-time error.